# Trouble parsing html files (to csv) using ElementTree xpath in python

Tags: python, html, csv, xpath

I am trying to parse a few thousand html files and dump the variables into a csv file (excel spreadsheet). I've come up against several roadblocks--the first one which was (thankfully) solve here, a few days ago. The (hopefully) final roadblock is this: I can not get it to properly parse the file using xpath. Below is a brief explanation, the python code and example of the html code.

The trouble starts here:

```
for node in tree.iter():
            name = node.attrib.get('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/p/span')
            if category =='/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/font':
            category=node.text
```

It runs, but does not parse. I do not get any traceback errors.

I think I am misunderstanding the logic of parsing with ElementTree.

There are several headers that are the same--it is therefor difficult to find a unique id/header. Here is an example of the html:

```
<span class="s1">Business: Give Back to the Community and Save Money 
on Equipment, Technology, Promotional Products, and Market<span 
class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span></span>
```

For which the xpath is:

```
    /html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/p/span
```

I would like to scrape the text from this span (among others) and put it in the excel spreadsheet.

You can see an example of a similar page [**HERE**](http://www.usprwire.com/Detailed/Banking_Finance_Investment/Confused.com_reveals_that_Life_Insurance_is_more_than_a_form_of_future_protection_284764.shtml)

At any rate, because many spans/headers are no uniquely identified, I think I should use xpath. However, I have yet to be able to figure out how to successfully use xpath commands with ElementTree. In searching the documentation, the answer to this question (as well as the logic) eludes me. I have read up on http://lxml.de/parsing.html as well as on this site and have yet to find something that works.

So far, the code iterates through all the files (in dropbox) nicely. It also creates the csv file and creates the headers (though not in separate columns, only as one line separated by semicolons-- but that should be easy to fix).

In sum, I would like it to parse the text from different lines on in each file (webpage) and dump it into the excel file.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

The python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv, codecs, os
from cStringIO import StringIO
# Note: you need to download and install this..
import unicodecsv
import lxml.html
# TODO: make into command line params (instead of constant)
CSV_FILE='output.csv'
HTML_PATH='/Users/C/data/Folder_NS'
f = open(CSV_FILE, 'wb')
w = unicodecsv.writer(f, encoding='utf-8', delimiter=';')
w.writerow(['file', 'category', 'about', 'title', 'subtitle', 'date', 'bodyarticle'])

 # redundant declarations:
category=''
about=''
title=''
subtitle=''
date=''
bodyarticle=''
print "headers created"

allFiles = os.listdir(HTML_PATH)
#with open(CSV_FILE, 'wb') as csvfile:
print "all defined"

for file in allFiles:
    #print allFiles
    if '.html' in file:
        print "in html loop"
        tree = lxml.html.parse(HTML_PATH+"/"+file)
        print '===================='
        print 'Parsing file: '+file
        print '===================='
        for node in tree.iter():
            name = node.attrib.get('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/p/span')

            if category =='/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/font':
            print 'Category:'
            category=node.text

f.close()
```

14 June 2015 (most recent change); I have just changed this section

```
        for node in tree.iter():
            name = node.attrib.get('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/p/span')

            if category =='/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/font':
            print 'Category:'
            category=node.text
```

to this:

```
    for node in tree.iter():
            row = dict.fromkeys(cols)
            Category_name = tree.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/p/span')
            row['category'] = Category_name[0].text_content().encode('utf-8')
```

It still runs, but does not parse.

Comment: Why don't you try with `tree.xpath()` function. Here the documentation: http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

Comment: @Birei Thank you for your comment. I have tried several things from that documentation. Most recently I changed the code -- I can't seem to put the changes in this comment, so I have edited the question above. It is still not parsing.

Comment: Can you provide a `html` page where we can test your `xpath`?

Comment: @Birei It is provided in the text above (" You can see an example of a similar page [HERE](http://www.usprwire.com/Detailed/Banking_Finance_Investment/Confused.com_reveals_that_Life_Insurance_is_more_than_a_form_of_future_protection_284764.shtml)") Please let me know if I can provide further detail, or detail in another form.

Comment: Ok. I test your `xpath` with that page and returns nothing. Where is the category you are looking for?

Comment: I just named that column in the cvs file 'category'. It refers to the first line in the text. For example, in the link above, I would like to capture the text "Banking, Finance & Investment: Confused.com reveals that Life Insurance is more than a form of future protection" where it would be put into the column in the csv file named 'category'.

Comment: To extract that part of text, try with: `response.xpath('/html//table/td/font/text()').extract()[0]`. It's tested with `scrapy` shell, but the `xpath` expression it's the same. And you don't need to use `iter()`, the initial `/` searches from the root node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80535/discussion-between-christine-and-birei).

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
from lxml import etree 
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO

data = requests.get('http://www.usprwire.com/Detailed/Banking_Finance_Investment/Confused.com_reveals_that_Life_Insurance_is_more_than_a_form_of_future_protection_284764.shtml').content
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
root = etree.parse(StringIO(data), parser)
category = root.xpath('//table/td/font/text()')
print category[0]
```

It uses `requests` library to download the `html` code of the page. You can choose whatever method that fits your needs. The important part is the `xpath` that searches any `<table>` followed by `<td>` followed by `<font>`, and it returns a list with two elements. The second one are blank characters and the first one contains the text.

Run it and yields just the sentence you are looking for:

```
Banking, Finance & Investment: Confused.com reveals that Life Insurance is more than a form of future protection
```

Comment: Thank you @Birei. But the code that you have posted (the `data = requests.get('http:...` in particular, would be useful were I wanting to strip the text from a (single) website. That particular link was posted to give an example of the html code for the files that I have that I need to parse the code from. I have about 4,000 of them. While the xpath is useful (and thank you), it is unclear to me still, how to scrape the text from those files (from within the loop) and have it show up into the xl file. Thank you for the time that you have already invested in answering this question already.

Comment: @Christine: With this example I showed you how to extract the category. It was your question. I suppose it won't work exactly for 4000 files, but that's your work, not mine. Did you inherit that code? If you are unsure, you should try to learn Python first and then think about the correct approach to solve the problem.

Comment: As I said, thank you very much for the assistance with the xpath portion of the code. Indeed, I am in the process of learning Python. And again, thank you for your time.